# Using integer as a parameter for POST HTTP request

Tags: spring, http

Is it possible to use simple types, such as integer, as a body for http post request? I have an example:

```
  public void setTimeout(@RequestBody Integer value) {
      storage.setTimeout(value);
  }
```

but i am unable to send a request that will trigger this successfully.

Comment: why don't you send it as String then parse it as integer ?

Comment: @boughti because that's ugly ? Spring can do it for you. Use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`. And for more specific type, like Date, you can register a custom editor into WebDataBinder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the annotation that you need is @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody
thus something like that

```
public void setTimeout(@ModelAttribute Integer value) {
      storage.setTimeout(value);
  }
```